# Can we have dataSource to multiple database

Tags: oracle, jboss, datasource, jndi, web.xml

I am having spring XML webservice application with oracle as a database. Right now i have datasource created using Jboss server. Also using both read and write transactions(insert,Read and update). Now we want to separate database for read(read) and wrtie(insert or update) transactions.

I have two database. I want to know how to use in my java web service and also in datasource.

e.g
 I have two address :

(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = svr1)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID =DB1))
 (ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = svr2)(PORT =1521))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID =DB2)))

In source code, I am using two jndi connection :

```
<display-name>Project</display-name>
<context-param>
        <description>Spring configuration file</description>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/production.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

In Production.xml, one database connection. 
I can do separate datasource and specify their jndi name into my web service but I want to avoid two war files in jboss server for two database. what is the other way I can use one application[one war file] with two database and can send to client only one wsdl file?